# Hiding the button

Tags: ios, iphone, if-statement, uibutton

I have struggle one issue ,i am developing one quiz app,here i am using one button purpose of back.In my app the 1st question i hide the back button,following the below code.

```
if ((questionIndex=1))
{
    backbutton.alpha=0;
}
```

In this app i am using code for going to next question,

```
 if (questionIndex < totalQuestionsCount - 1) {
    [self loadQuestionsWithIndex:questionIndex + 1];
     questionIndex++;
}
```

and back to the question,

```
if (questionIndex > totalQuestionsCount - 1) {
    [self loadQuestionsWithIndex:questionIndex + 1];
    questionIndex--;
```

}

After going to next question the back button is display,but while i want to again back to the first question, i need the back button is hide but here it is show.
It is simple but i am confusing how can it fixing can you please suggest me.Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `button.hidden = YES` or `button.enabled = NO`

Comment: Do you Make the index +1 for Every new question? Then you could make it -1 for Every back Button click. Could you provide a bit more code?

Comment: here all is working fine but i need to hide the button when i am in first question.

Comment: button.hidden=YES and button.enabled=NO is not working for that @Bhumit

Answer (score 0):

For going to back you should do it unless you comes to the first question, so check for question number 1:

```
if (questionIndex > 0) {
    [self loadQuestionsWithIndex:questionIndex + 1];
    questionIndex--;
}
```

and use either `button.hidden = YES;` or `button.enabled = YES` as suggested in comments.